# Angular Controller accessing individual items

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, controller

I am working on an Angular app (rails backend, separate repo for backend) with a many to many relation between items and outfits, with outfit_items as the join table model between them. In my angular show controller for outfits, I am trying to write the delete function to remove items from an outfit.

```
    this.destroy = function(){
      self.outfit = OutfitFactory.get({id: $stateParams.id}, function(){
        self.outfit_item = OutfitItemFactory.query({id: $stateParams.id}, function(){
          self.outfit_item.$remove_from_outfit({id: self.items.id, outfit_id: self.outfit_id});
    })
  })
}
```

When I console what `outfit_item` is it just shows all of the items for the outfit.  I tried using a `.get` instead but got an angular error `Error: $resource:badcfg
Response does not match configured parameter`.  How else can I access the individual item here so I can run the remove function just on that?

Also, I have the function defined in my rails controller for outfits as follows:

```
def remove_from_outfit
  @outfit = Outfit.find(params[:outfit_id])
  @outfit_item = @outfit.outfit_item
  @outfit_item.destroy
  render json: {message: "success"}, status: :ok
end
```

Comment: does $stateParams.id refer to the ID for the outfit or the outfit_item?